# Link cannot be clicked; no hover, or anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm having a little problem with my push menu.

Here is my HTML code for the menu:

```
<nav id="menu">
<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Text</a>
<ul>
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">Pyronobic <img src="pyronobic-logo-v2.png" style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" /></span>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is, the .menu-link link can't be clicked, and I don't know why.

Here is my CSS for it:

```
.menu-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(Assets/menu.svg);
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(".menu-link").click(function() {
    $("#menu").toggleClass("active");
    $(".container").toggleClass("active");
});
```

## menu.active CSS:

```
#menu.active {
-webkit-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
-moz-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
-o-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
}
.container.active {
 -webkit-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
 -moz-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
 -o-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
 -ms-transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
 transform: translate(-13.725em, 0px);
}
```

I have tested it before by taking the link OUT of the Nav tag, but when it is inside the nav tag, it doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance for your help!

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tRio/4aPT2/3/).

Comment: remove hash(#) from html link tag.

Comment: Your link is empty `<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Put some Text</a>`

Comment: Btw, `<a>` vs `</ahyb>` seems dubious ...

Comment: Provide a fiddle. Anyway you should be doing it differently

Comment: You're right -deleting '-(

Comment: Where's the active class you toggle? And side note, typo in `background-poisition-x`

Comment: OK, thanks. I've fixed all of those typos and I added some text, but it still isn't clickable. I have no idea why. Oh, and the active class is the #menu css. I'll add that in there.

Comment: Is you <nav> tag is closed?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it didn't show up in the code because of formatting errors. I've edited it back in C-link

Comment: Please provide fiddle or link to your code.

Comment: INVALID HTML. ULs can not contain a child that is a span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the property left assigned -50px. May be this cause the issue. You need to work on position.

Apply your css like blow.

```
.menu-link {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
left: 50px;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background: no-repeat;
background-image: url(Assets/menu.svg);
background-position-x: 50%;
background-position-y: 50%;
background-size: 50%;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
background-position: center center;
z-index: 99;
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
-o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jYN2/1/

Comment: why do you think that might be a mistake alignment?

Comment: check the fiddle. it is wokring fine. When you click the test link, menu got added with active class.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

`<a href="#menu" class="menu-link"></a>`

**With**

`<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Some Text</a>`

Comment: no matter the a link is empty since the width and height is defined.